# access struts2 java static variables in javascript .js file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, static-variables

I understand that all javascript files are not compiled by the server, as it is simply served directly.

However, in my backend, most variables are organized as static final variables so that when things are changed that can be changed in one place altogether.

Currently I have no way to maintain the coordination between the javascript and the backend action class variables.Seems like the only suggestion online is to create javascript in jsp files. Is there any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically create your javascript file from a JSP.

e.g: in your html or main jsp file you have the following

dyanmicJavascript.action will call your action class which will then return a jsp. The jsp will have just the javascript code (NO HTML STUFF). so your jsp will look like.

//tag library stuff + other jsp specific stuff
// plain javascript code follows
var globalVariable = 10;
var dynamicVariables =

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative to creating js from jsp files*

Set the javascript variable in a JSP and then use it in javascript (.js) files

For e.g.

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      var contextPath="${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
      var otherStaticVariable="<s:property value="@ConstantsClass@GlobalConstantVar"/>";
    </script>
    <script src="js/other.js"></script>
</head>
//Rest of the page
</html>
```

Now other.js can directly refer contextPath & otherStaticVariable within it's code.

I've used similar code in few of my projects.